# how to join smaller df to larger df and use smaller as key that can repeat?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, concatenation

I have a df that looks like this:

| Process Step Name | Sort A | Sort B | Sort C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sub Name | 2 | 3 | 4 |

and one that looks like this:

| Process Step Name | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sub Name | Value | Value | Value |

I want to iterate through the second dataframe, and add columns A B C depending on the Process Step Name, but there are only 21 rows in the first df (each process sub name has their own sorted value for each column) and around 100000 in the second one. I can't figure out how to do this, any suggestions?
The result would look like:

| Process Step Name | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Sort A | Sort B | Sort 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sub Name | Value | Value | Value | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.merge`:

```py
out = df2.merge(df1, on="Process Step Name", how="left")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Process Step Name Column 1 Column 2 Column 3  Sort A  Sort B  Sort C
0          Sub Name    Value    Value    Value       2       3       4
```

---

Dataframes used:

**`df1`**:

```
  Process Step Name  Sort A  Sort B  Sort C
0          Sub Name       2       3       4
```

**`df2`**:

```
  Process Step Name Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
0          Sub Name    Value    Value    Value
```